# Jar file does not have access to write to files with an extension

Tags: java, eclipse

On a Windows 10 machine, I have a Java project in Eclipse.
When I run the main method in Eclipse using a launcher, the program correctly writes to a csv file. It works when the filename is an arbitrary extension or no extension as well. I am using the class FileWriter to write files.

I exported the project as a runnable jar, and when I run the jar in the command prompt using "java -jar", and I use the extension ".csv",".txt", ".doc", ".xls" (among others), I get a FileNotFoundException that says access is denied. However, when I provide a filename with no extension or with an extension like ".foo", running the jar successfully writes out a file. I'd like to get it so that the jar writes out a file with a "csv" extension.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: csv\report.csv (Access is denied)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:291)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:234)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:66)
    at project.TestRunner.createCSVFile(TestRunner.java:103)
```

**UPDATE**
Before I was using a 64-bit version of Java 16 (see below).

```
java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I used a 32-bit version of Java 8, the problem disappeared.

```
java version "1.8.0_301"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The problem ended up being an overprotective anti-virus software.

Comment: Neither java nor any OS decides to block .csv specifically. Whatever the explanation is of what you're observing, there aren't enough details in this question to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: Most surely those files were already created by Eclipse and you don't have permissions to rewrite them. Delete the existing files (if any), and run the jar as admin. As @rzwitserloot states there's no link whatsoever in extensions regarding OS blocks

Comment: Does the directory `csv` actually exist?  What is the execution context of the program?  (ie what is the working directory?)

Comment: Yes, the directory `csv` exists. It is up one level from the working directory. I tried deleting the files and running as an administrator and I got the same errors.

Comment: Not sure this is your problem, but if you haven't found a solution yet, double check that the "file" you're trying to open is not actually a directory. On Windows, I've seen an error just like that when I've accidently tried to open a _directory_ as if it were a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are mistaken about the cause of this.

Windows file extensions are (fundamentally) a convention.  As you noted, Java will happily read and write files with any extension ... or no extension.  The Java itself doesn't care, and the Windows OS allows it.

Apparently, you are *seeing* some different behaviors when you put your application in a JAR file, and run it using `java -jar ...`.

Firstly, this is NOT Java's doing.  Java is entirely agnostic about the file extensions.  And there is no substantial difference between executing from a JAR or from within an IDE.  (Assuming that the JAR was made correctly.   And even then, the differences I am thinking about wouldn't have *this* effect.)

Secondly, I don't think this is Windows doing.  As far as I know, Windows itself does not implement file access control that is sensitive to filename extensions.  (Or if it does, I can't find this in the MS Windows documentation.)

That leaves the following possibilities:

- It could potentially be something like an over-protective antivirus, or a localization to Windows access control.  (I don't know if this is *technically* possible ...)
- The most likely explanation is that you are misinterpreting the error messages.  For example:

  - They could be talking about the permissions on the directory rather than the file.
  - It could be that you are trying to overwrite an existing file which you don't have write permissions for.
  - You are using relative pathnames, and are running in a different "current directory".
  - Something else like that.

---

**UPDATE** - Based on the stacktrace, I suspect that this is a "current directory" problem.

Comment: I've seen a similar error when I've accidently tried to open a _directory_ as if it were a file. Not sure if that's what the OP's problem is though, unless they've accidently created a directory with a name that would otherwise indicate a file.